# Site.com vs Community

Tags: community, site.com, guest-user

Client is using Unlimited Edition (UE) Salesforce Org. When ever we are creating a Community, it is creating a Site and a guest User along with the Community.

As per

1. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_sites.htm&type=5 and
2. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000006778&language=en_US&type=1

EE/UE Orgs are allowed to create up to 25 sites hence the 25 guest user licenses.

I know maximum number of communities we can create is 100.

If my understanding is correct (i.e. we are not allowed to create Site and Guest users more then 25) then my question is what will happen in terms of Site and guest users when ever we are going to create beyond 25 Communities?